# CKEditor having issues with images

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor

I've got an issue when adding images using CKEditor, this is the process:

- Image is added in CKEditor: http://cl.ly/3h2r3M1x3l053F1b0Z0T
- This gets sent through to my server: http://cl.ly/46071p1S1s0G2S27240t
- How CKEditor then deals with this: http://cl.ly/0d2A2v0W0P0t1i0U060x

As a result I get a really garbled image tag at the end of it...

Does anyone have thoughts how to prevent this from happening?

Many thanks.

Comment: which version of CI are you using?

Comment: Are you applying  any filtering on posted content? (XSS_clean, htmlentities)

Comment: Ahhh @DamienPirsy you're spot on. I've got global XSS filtering on. Disabling that solves my issue. My issue now is that XSS filtering is a not a good thing!

Comment: Well, it *is* a good thing, it's just that it confuses CKEditor (and TinyMCE as well, IIRC)

Comment: Indeed. Going to go for a little rewrite now. Thanks for the help Damien!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have global XSS_clean on and allow some url's to not clean `style` attribute with creating your version of Security.php file. Everything is described here [style attribute lost after update](http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/entry/codeigniter-202-tinymce-or-ckeditor-style-attribute-lost-after-update)